# Convert web.config file to .htaccess PHP

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, iis, web-config, web.config-transform

Can anybody help me to convert this web.config file to .htaccess.

I'm trying to search on google but unable to find the desired result.

Here is my webconfig.

```
<rules>
    <rule name="HTTP api" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*/)?api/(.*)$" ignoreCase="true"/>
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile"
                ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory"
                ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}api/http.php/{R:2}"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="Site pages" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*/)?pages/(.*)$" ignoreCase="true"/>
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile"
                ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory"
                ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}pages/index.php/{R:2}"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="Staff applications" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*/)?scp/apps/(.*)$" ignoreCase="true"/>
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile"
                ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory"
                ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}scp/apps/dispatcher.php/{R:2}"/>
    </rule>
</rules>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule "^(.*/)?api/(.*)$" $1api/http.php/$2 [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule "^(.*/)?pages/(.*)$" $1pages/index.php/$2 [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule "^(.*/)?scp/apps/(.*)$" $1scp/apps/dispatcher.php/$2 [NC]
```